# How to sync local DB data with a remote DB?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a DB locally. I want its data to stay sync with a remote DB. Like, I write to the DB locally immediately but in the background, with a threshold of (for example) 10 seconds it accumulates changes and sends it to the remote DB in order to stay sync.

(I understand that there may be some conflicts, like two separate apps have send me the same row change but with different values - this is separate question of how it should be handled, I'm ok with the simplest tactic, "who is the last, that one is right")

I use PostgreSQL (however, it's not important, I can switch). Are there available options? Some adapters? Or other DBMS?

I suppose I should handle this by my own business logic, by my own code on top of the app, not the DB. But I may miss something...

Comment: I think the right term you are missing here is "replication". What do you mean by "remote DB"? Is it connected in the same LAN or over WAN (internet)? Is it the same type of database (also a PostgreSQL) or something else?

Comment: @Ancoron it's the same DBMS (postgresql), the same DB structure/schema (however, it changes sometimes and may temporarily be different - which is another source of conflicts), but stored remotely, on another machine, not accessible in LAN

Comment: _"however, it changes sometimes and may temporarily be different [...]"_ That's going to be a deal-breaker for any reliable solution, whether or not you're implementing it yourself. Using WAN I'd suggest [Streaming Replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION) as you just need a one-directional "backup" as far as I understand. Just be sure to require SSL connections or establish a VPN.